# get only a COMMAND column in cygwin for ps command

Tags: macos, cygwin

In Cygwin, I can get the list of running processes by following command:

```
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
    13160       1   13160      13160  ?         197609 13:42:18 /usr/bin/mintty
S   15404    2852   15404      16776  pty2      197609 13:59:29 /usr/bin/vi
     2852   12912    2852      11244  pty2      197609 13:42:54 /usr/bin/bash
     9864       1    9864       9864  ?         197609 13:11:32 /usr/bin/mintty
S   10500    2852    1692       1452  pty2      197609 14:09:42 /usr/bin/less
S   17644    2852   17644      11880  pty2      197609 14:00:15 /usr/bin/vi
    12912       1   12912      12912  ?         197609 13:42:54 /usr/bin/mintty
     8432    2852    8432      12020  pty2      197609 14:10:05 /usr/bin/ps
    17092   13160   17092      14720  pty1      197609 13:42:18 /usr/bin/bash
```

However, I just want the `COMMAND` column but not all columns like this:

```
COMMAND
/usr/bin/mintty
/usr/bin/vi
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mintty
/usr/bin/less
/usr/bin/vi
/usr/bin/mintty
 /usr/bin/ps
/usr/bin/bash
```

In MAC, I can do this by the following command:

```
ps -o command
```

The same command is not working for cygwin in windows because the `-o` option is not there in ps for cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use awk to print only the selected column.

```
$ ps |awk '{ if (NF==8) {print $8} else {print $9}}'
COMMAND
/usr/bin/ps
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mintty
```

For more learning:
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-17

Comment: Paths with spaces will completely break this, and they are popular on windows.